# How can I tell if my PS4 is hacked?

Tags: ps4

I've noted the hacks out there for PS4; most of them involve completely bypassing the PS4's root-level security.  Some involve access via USB, others may be remotely installable.  For a time, unknown persons had access to my PS4 physically.

I've noticed remote-play like effects and other local problems while playing games that didn't exist before.  I'd like to know if there's a way to see if the original firmware and/or certificates, etc, are in place.

Comment: As far as I know no one has gotten as far as creating hacked PlayStation 4 firmware, and you have have be using an old version (1.76) of the firmware for the known exploits to work. If you're running the latest firmware (3.11) your console hasn't been hacked.

Comment: @Ross,  that last sentence is **VERY** dangerous to assume (just in general). Sure, there might not be any known hacks to v3.11, but I don't think anybody can state that as an absolute fact.

Comment: @DangerZone totally agree.   There is an ocean between what is widely known in security and what exists in the wild.   Probably, everything is hackable, and remotely at that.  Just because it isn't announced doesn't mean it isn't possible and isn't happening.  State actors keep these secrets all the time.

Comment: @rcd If you want to be paranoid, then "state actors" have the means to hack any device in your home. If you think that's a possibility then there's no assurance anyone can give you that you haven't be hacked. But realistically, no, your PS4 hasn't been hacked. There's nothing to be gained from it, and I said there's no indication that any one in the PS4 hacking community actually has the capability to do it. The fact is that the PS4 hackers haven't wasted any time in announcing their progress. They're not as shadowy or as secretive as you assume.

Comment: I work in security and could be a target of state actors.   Thus it could be hacked in this case.  I've seen realtime hacks occur during gaming, that you wouldn't believe.   So again, how can one verify firmware etc?

Comment: @rcd factory reset? or [this](http://ps4firmware.com/) can verify firmware

Comment: @Aequitas Thanks, but that software was to check Sony's site for firmware updates.  A factory reset might help, but if the system has been rooted, that would quite possibly not help at all (see rootkit).

Comment: What issues are you having specifically? The PS4 has occasionally has stuttering issues due to extended play or suspending apps that can be similar to Remote Play issues. A root doesn't seem completely out of the question, PS4 is running a modified version of FreeBSD and a modded WebKit for a browser which is how fail0verflow was able to do their console hack.

Comment: @GoodSirTheSir two examples: I've received text messages from numbers that somehow "don't exist", saying things like "watch this", or "wait for it".  Then Mario or Snake or whoever will run in circles and go jump off of a cliff, resulting in death.  Once in Breath of the Wild, I entered a bunker-like area, and literally, a sound file started playing that sounded like an old tv show laugh track, and enemies' faces (the textures on the polygons) were replaced with random people whom I have never seen.  I sat and watched this in amazement, then rebooted, returned to the area, and it was gone.

Answer (score 2):

To be on the safe side, you should use the [PS4 Recovery Mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDfG7x2LkkQ) to re-install the system software via USB (Option 3). You should only download the official firmware update from https://www.playstation.com rather than rely on third-party or unofficial sources.

If you want to be extra safe, you should do a full backup of the console to a external hard drive and then reset the PS4 using Option 7 from the PS4 Recovery Mode. This will delete everything on the console, including the system software, saved data and games, so **use with caution**. Once reset, you can either restore your backed-up data or download your games again.

Comment: This sound like a good option.  Is it possible to download the firmware to USB, though?  Never mind, I found the instructions in case anyone wants to do it: https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/system-updates/ps4/#newinstallation.  The only problem I see is the possibility that the firmware can be updated remotely.  If so, it would require constantly doing this procedure.